# Logging on ISP Config broke my PHP sessions and cookies forever

Tags: php, session-cookies, ispconfig

*To explain my problem I have to add some context info:*

We have a website, it works with sessions and has been working for 7 years with no problems, except for our server administrator, he can not login, and we never knew why... until now...

Our Server administrator is on vacations, so I had to do some of his works, it include login on ISP Config which is located on the same server and domain using a different port (8080), I logged there, to check some values and then when I go back to our website, I could not login, just as our server administrator.

Doing some debug I found it is a problem with sessions, on every refresh `session_id()` changes.

using `ini_get` I got `session.cookie_domain` and `session.cookie_secure` are empty.

If I do a `print_r($_COOKIE)` there is no `PHPSESSID`, if I set it to any value it dissapears, even if I write a long expiration It is not saved, If I set 2 cookies like this:

```
setcookie("PHPSESSID", "MYSESSION", time()+365*24*60*60, '/');
setcookie("a", "b", time()+365*24*60*60, '/');
```

and then `print_r($_COOKIE);` I get this:

```
Array ( [a] => b )
```

I don't have any .htaccess, so there is no rules in my side, seems like there is something in ISP config what changed the way I store cookies.

I could ask on webmasters.stackexchange.com but I need a PHP answer to set the new values when someone log in my website after logging in ISP config.

*This is my current code to test:*

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");
session_start();
//$_SESSION[b_id]=1;
setcookie("PHPSESSID", "GTS", time()+365*24*60*60, '/');
setcookie("a", "b", time()+365*24*60*60, '/');
echo "<div>b_id: $_SESSION[b_id]</div>";
echo "<div>session_id: ".session_id()."</div>";
echo "<div>cookie_domain: ".ini_get('session.cookie_domain')."</div>";
echo "<div>save_path: ".ini_get('session.save_path')."</div>";
echo "<div>cookie_secure: ".ini_get('session.cookie_secure')."</div>";
print_r($_COOKIE);
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r(ini_get_all());
echo "</pre>";*/
?>
```

*This is the output, (session_id value changes each time):*

```
b_id:
session_id: du95eljbkct54qktvcd18a7ej0
cookie_domain:
save_path: /var/lib/php/sessions
cookie_secure:
Array ( [a] => b )
```

*This is the output of `ini_get_all()` function:*

```
[session.auto_start] => Array   (
    [global_value] => 0
    [local_value] => 0
    [access] => 2
)
[session.cache_expire] => Array (
    [global_value] => 180
    [local_value] => 180
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cache_limiter] => Array    (
    [global_value] => nocache
    [local_value] => nocache
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_domain] => Array    (
    [global_value] => 
    [local_value] => 
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_httponly] => Array  (
    [global_value] => 
    [local_value] => 
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_lifetime] => Array  (
    [global_value] => 0
    [local_value] => 3600
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_path] => Array  (
    [global_value] => /
    [local_value] => /
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_secure] => Array    (
    [global_value] => 
    [local_value] => 
    [access] => 7
)
[session.entropy_file] => Array (
    [global_value] => /dev/urandom
    [local_value] => /dev/urandom
    [access] => 7
)
[session.entropy_length] => Array   (
    [global_value] => 32
    [local_value] => 32
    [access] => 7
)
[session.gc_divisor] => Array   (
    [global_value] => 1000
    [local_value] => 1000
    [access] => 7
)
[session.gc_maxlifetime] => Array   (
    [global_value] => 1440
    [local_value] => 1440
    [access] => 7
)
[session.gc_probability] => Array   (
    [global_value] => 0
    [local_value] => 0
    [access] => 7
)
[session.hash_bits_per_character] => Array  (
    [global_value] => 5
    [local_value] => 5
    [access] => 7
)
[session.hash_function] => Array    (
    [global_value] => 0
    [local_value] => 0
    [access] => 7
)
[session.lazy_write] => Array   (
    [global_value] => 1
    [local_value] => 1
    [access] => 7
)
[session.name] => Array (
    [global_value] => PHPSESSID
    [local_value] => PHPSESSID
    [access] => 7
)
[session.referer_check] => Array    (
    [global_value] => 
    [local_value] => 
    [access] => 7
)
[session.save_handler] => Array (
    [global_value] => files
    [local_value] => files
    [access] => 7
)
[session.save_path] => Array    (
    [global_value] => /var/lib/php/sessions
    [local_value] => /var/lib/php/sessions
    [access] => 7
)
[session.serialize_handler] => Array    (
    [global_value] => php
    [local_value] => php
    [access] => 7
)
[session.upload_progress.cleanup] => Array  (
    [global_value] => 1
    [local_value] => 1
    [access] => 2
)
[session.upload_progress.enabled] => Array  (
    [global_value] => 1
    [local_value] => 1
    [access] => 2
)
[session.upload_progress.freq] => Array (
    [global_value] => 1%
    [local_value] => 1%
    [access] => 2
)
[session.upload_progress.min_freq] => Array (
    [global_value] => 1
    [local_value] => 1
    [access] => 2
)
[session.upload_progress.name] => Array (
    [global_value] => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
    [local_value] => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
    [access] => 2
)
[session.upload_progress.prefix] => Array   (
    [global_value] => upload_progress_
    [local_value] => upload_progress_
    [access] => 2
)
[session.use_cookies] => Array  (
    [global_value] => 1
    [local_value] => 1
    [access] => 7
)
[session.use_only_cookies] => Array (
    [global_value] => 1
    [local_value] => 1
    [access] => 7
)
[session.use_strict_mode] => Array  (
    [global_value] => 0
    [local_value] => 0
    [access] => 7
)
[session.use_trans_sid] => Array    (
    [global_value] => 0
    [local_value] => 0
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_domain] => Array    (
    [global_value] => 
    [local_value] => 
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_httponly] => Array  (
    [global_value] => 
    [local_value] => 
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_lifetime] => Array  (
    [global_value] => 0
    [local_value] => 3600
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_path] => Array  (
    [global_value] => /
    [local_value] => /
    [access] => 7
)
[session.cookie_secure] => Array    (
    [global_value] => 
    [local_value] => 
    [access] => 7
)
```

How to go back my session system to default as before logging in ISP config?

---

*Answering Iłya Bursov questions*

Opening page in incognito mode let me login normally and PHPSESSID doesn't change.

Clearing cookies didn't work, PHPSESSID still changing.

phpinfo gave me some relevant info:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ositfoouhvosgcklk2k14r7t25; expires=Fri, 07-Dec-2018 19:28:01 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
// This is the same time it was created, so it is creating and expiring inmediately!

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
// 1981!?
```

I have a co-worker (in the same network) who can login in my website.

---

**After 2 days, I am unable to fix the problem, we made a new test today to reproduce this error, our web developer logged on ISP Config and now he is unable to log in in my system!!**

Same error as me and our server administrator.

I am using Chrome in Windows 10.

ISP Config version 3.1.11

It seems like this guy had the same issue 6 years ago: [PHPSESSID not being saved to cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255214/phpsessid-not-being-saved-to-cookie)

Comment: Seems like this is more of a hosting question, not a PHP question.

Comment: However you may ask here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting

Comment: I could ask there but I need a PHP answer to reset the new values when someone log in my website after logging in ISP config.

Comment: Include information about your code & session data if you want a PHP answer.  Otherwise, this is broad and doesn't seem programming related.

Comment: Done, I included my test code and its output.

Comment: first thing to try is to open page in incognito mode (or clear cookies), also - can check output of phpinfo (and probably post parts about cookies/sessions) here

Comment: Using incognito mode let me login, I made a phpinfo and I get some relevant data I posted in the question.

Comment: try to print server's time, ie print `time()` and then convert it to human-readable format https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: I made this `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());` and got this `2018-12-10 11:42:43`

Comment: Have you set timezone in your application?

Comment: My server is GMT, do sessions works with local time? my local computer is GMT-3.

Comment: Which browser do you use? I know a tool on Google Chrome that can lock the cookies so the `PHPSESSID` won't be deleted. Maybe that will help with the investigation.

Comment: Is that ISP panel itself written in PHP as well? I’d start by renaming the session something else, and see if that helps, because it sounds like a possible overlap between the two systems here.

Comment: @misorude Yes, it is PHP, even if I create a session to a name like `foobar123` it expires and PHPSESSID changes.

Comment: Koen Hollander, I am using Chrome.

Comment: Can you tell us what's your session rules? (if you ever set some or if there's some already setup in a php file)

Comment: vincent-d, I never set them, I going to add to my post the results of `ini_get_all()`

Comment: _“even if I create a session to a name like foobar123 it expires and PHPSESSID changes”_ - it should not have been PHPSESSID any more to begin with, if you changed the session name. (Make sure you did that before the session is started/picked up again.)

Comment: misorude, Oh, I understand!, I changed the name `session_name('Foo')` and it stopped changing its value and keeps correctly all the variables!, so, seems like the issues is using the default name `PHPSESSID`, I could fix the issue renaming the variable for my whole systems, but, I would like to restore `PHPSESSID` variable, why it is reseting/expiring?

Comment: Have you seen the answer to this post, pretty interesting read and may help with your sessions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly

Comment: Of course, you are setting phpsessid arbitrarily, that is the PHP SESSION ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Well, four months later of testing, I going to answer my own question to help others having this issue.*

ISP Config uses the default PHP name session id, so, if you run a different system in the same domain you can not use the same id.

**the first way** to solve this problem is doing what [@misorude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10283047/misorude) said in his comment, change all the session names to a different name before starting any session:

```
session_name('MySystem'); // your session string ID
session_start();
```

For your session string ID use any string you want, use always the same on your whole system and do not use a the default value "PHPSESSID".

Session expired too fast, this is because I was running 2 systems in the same domain as [second2none](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9645594/second2none) link commented.

shorter `session.gc_maxlifetime` time, will be used for all the systems in the domain.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly) shows a **second alternative way** to solve it changing the session directory, calling the [session_save_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) function.

There is **a third way** if you do not want to change the session name id or the session directory in all your files, you can also change the [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) configuration as [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%C3%81lvaro-gonz%C3%A1lez) suggested.