# SessionID is not communicated between Client/Server in webpack4 project with php/apache backend

Tags: php, apache, session, webpack, zurb-foundation

I'm testing out ZURB foundation which runs on webpack4, babel7 and gulp (as taskrunner). My backend is built with a no-installation, latest XAMPP. I'm running apache from it and my php.

The basis for client/server communication works. 
Im using jquery AJAX to call php scripts and push/pull data to/from MariaDB. 
Now I want some persistence for my login functionality.

I configured my php.ini so that the session files are located inside /Session folder which resides inside the src/assets folder of my ZURB Foundation project.
Here is a (rather large) excerpt from my php.ini. I included a bit more stuff because as I've learnt here [How to configure session.save_path inside php.ini for webpack4 based website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623548/how-to-configure-session-save-path-inside-php-ini-for-webpack4-based-website?noredirect=1#comment101757551_57623548) 
this might also be about cookies. And Im totally new to all this and Ive never configured any cookie functionality so far so I dont know which one of these settings might be important.

```
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
; http://php.net/session.save-path
;session.save_path = "\xampp\tmp"
session.save_path = "D:\foundationtests\src\assets\Session"
; Whether to use strict session mode.
; Strict session mode does not accept an uninitialized session ID, and
; regenerates the session ID if the browser sends an uninitialized session ID.
; Strict mode protects applications from session fixation via a session adoption
; vulnerability. It is disabled by default for maximum compatibility, but
; enabling it is encouraged.
; https://wiki.php.net/rfc/strict_sessions
session.use_strict_mode = 0

; Whether to use cookies.
; http://php.net/session.use-cookies
session.use_cookies = 1

; http://php.net/session.cookie-secure
;session.cookie_secure =

; This option forces PHP to fetch and use a cookie for storing and maintaining
; the session id. We encourage this operation as it's very helpful in combating
; session hijacking when not specifying and managing your own session id. It is
; not the be-all and end-all of session hijacking defense, but it's a good start.
; http://php.net/session.use-only-cookies
session.use_only_cookies = 1

; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
; http://php.net/session.name
session.name = PHPSESSID

; Initialize session on request startup.
; http://php.net/session.auto-start
session.auto_start = 0

; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-lifetime
session.cookie_lifetime = 0

; The path for which the cookie is valid.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-path
session.cookie_path = /

; The domain for which the cookie is valid.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-domain
session.cookie_domain =

; Whether or not to add the httpOnly flag to the cookie, which makes it
; inaccessible to browser scripting languages such as JavaScript.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-httponly
session.cookie_httponly =

; Add SameSite attribute to cookie to help mitigate Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF/XSRF)
; Current valid values are "Lax" or "Strict"
; https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07
session.cookie_samesite =

; Handler used to serialize data. php is the standard serializer of PHP.
; http://php.net/session.serialize-handler
session.serialize_handler = php
```

so the current behavior is that session files are created, but not accessed. 
I have the following phpExample1:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["id"] = 10;
 ?>
```

Then I have phpExample2:

```
<?php
session_start();
$test = $_SESSION["id"];

echo $test;
 ?>
```

In this case I get the following error on my `console.log()` in the receiving JS code:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: loggedUserID in <b>D:\foundationtests\src\assets\php\globallyUsedFunctions\retrieveLoggedUserID.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

There seems to be an issue that the session file containing the users session data cant be accessed, probably because the session ID was somehow lost/not transmitted. This is also indicated by the fact that phpExample1 actually creates a session file with the respective data, but when I run phpExample2, a new, empty session file is created. This also concurs with the php documentation which says that `session_start();` either starts a new session or continues an existing one. 
I have no idea which parts of my backend/front-end, webproject or XAMPP I have to lay my hands on to fix this problem. I'm also somehow lost on how to google this ^^

I already looked into php documentation and I also tried echoing `session_id()` from my phpExample2 after I had executed phpExample1. But I get an empty string to my `console.log()`, so basically nothing was found, which again fits into the context of session_start() creating new sessions instead of continuing the existing one.

EDIT:
As per request, I post the var_dump() result of $_REQUEST and $_COOKIE here:

```
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
```

EDIT2:
The response headers from the phpExample1 AJAX:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: io=27GSwfgTRlPYm5-nAAAU; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 09:57:40 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Okay I think I got the wrong one, THIS one should be right!

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 10:09:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.8
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=aaghn2jdh4hgfhlsagoep5lqvr; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

EDIT3:
the AJAX headers to phpExample1 look like this:

responseHeader:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 10:38:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.8
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=bu2ggojkrkpqen33kh6r63pd36; path=/; domain=localhost:8099
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

requestHeader:

```
Host: localhost:8099
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 115
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8000/login.html
```

Then, the headers for phpExample2 (the php where the session should be continued and the data written to $_SESSION should be accessed) after phpExample1 had been executed:

responseHeader:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 10:38:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.8
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3isk6nf8fi2k3n4mfcfmtkv62d; path=/; domain=localhost:8099
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 367
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

requestHeader:

```
Host: localhost:8099
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8000/login.html
Content-Length: 0
```

Note that for these requests, I had set
session.cookie_domain = localhost:8099 
inside my php.ini. I also tried out :8000 for this, but it didnt change anything except ofc for the headers showing a different port.

Comment: Can you please dump the contents of the $_REQUEST and $_COOKIE globals on request number 2?

Comment: @santamanno Edited it into my post :=)

Comment: It seems the session is not kept between requests. Is it performed against a different ip? Do you close the browser in the meantime? Can you dump document.cookie on the JavaScript site of things please?

Comment: @santamanno About the session being performed against a different ip: I have no idea, what file do I need to take a look into?
I don't close the browser in the meantime, also, the site is not refreshed or anything. phpExample1 is called from the same site as phpExample2. They are called by separate onclick events, which execute the jquery AJAX (method: POST). 

I tried to console.log() "document.cookie" but get an empty string. I tried to "window.dump()" it but I get neither an error nor any reaction my console. Or where do I need to look for this dump()? I've never used it or heard of it

Comment: Ok, the cookie is not received and stored by the browser or not sent by the server. Can you please show the response headers of the first AJAX request from the browser Web Inspector?

Comment: @Santamanno Okay, I hope I got this right:
I expanded the XHR request in my console, and there were several headers and I took all the contents from the response header. I will edit them into my OP in a few sec.

Comment: There should be a Set-Cookie header somewhere with the "PHPSESSID" name, either on the the first page load or on the first AJAX request. When the AJAX requests back to the server, it should send a "Cookie" header so PHP can restore the session. Can you investigate why this cookie is not kept?

Comment: @santamanno Sry I think at first I posted the wrong one. The second should be right. 
I misinterpreted the first one which already happened when just loading the site. I thought it would be the right one because it was a POST request and I thought the only POST requests happening on my website would be the ones created by my AJAX. I was wrong as it seems...^^ Sry!

Comment: @santamanno 
I found a post on SO where a similar problem appeared
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255214/phpsessid-not-being-saved-to-cookie

I found out that my "session.cookie_domain = " inside php.ini had an empty string. I'm not sure whether this causes some default behavior to redirect to localhost or not, but I tried adding just "localhost" and restarted my apache successfully. 

However, the behavior hasn't changed.
Do I need to specify "localhost:XXXX"? And if so, what port do I have to chose? The website (8000) or the apache/php (8099)?

Comment: Sorry for the endless comments, does the "Cookie" header gets sent back to the server with the next AJAX request?

Comment: @santamanno 
No problem :)
I edited in the request and response headers for both the phpExample1 AJAX and the phpExample2 AJAX (after phpExample1 had been executed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198479/discussion-between-santamanno-and-baryon123).